# rewrite url using .htaccess in joomla 3.0

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I need to rewrite url using .htaccess.

This is my url `index.php/component/mb2portfolio/project/2-cum-sociis`

How can I change this to `/skill_pages/2_skill_name.html` is it possible in .htaccess

Note : I tried with `RewriteRule` in `.htaccess` and it works fine but for other default urls with .html as suffix not working because of this script.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: yes I tried with `RewriteRule` in .htaccess and it works fine but for other default urls with `.html` as suffix not working because of this script.

Comment: Please post your `.htaccess` `RewriteRule`s in your question. (And for future reference, it is always better to post your code so that we can help you along - see the [FAQ].)